# Passing Log4j2 ThreadContext across Threads in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j2, spring-rest

Goal is to provide unique Id to all the log statements per request (which can spawn multiple threads due to AsynRestTemplate usage). I have a situation where "ListenableFutureCallback" onFailure() is retuning an exception. When  the exception is thrown, Global Exception Handler is written extending "ResponseEntityExceptionHandler". I need to pass Log4j2 ThreadContext from onFailure to  ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. someErrorHandler() method, so that log4j can log unique id for that request to correlate what happened to that call.

I can provide more details in case required. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess, but I would see if you can add the ThreadContext attributes as headers to the response. I would think they would be available in all the places you want them.

Comment: Yeap, I got that and that is how i wanted to do but, i am bit confused/ not sure about how to access headers in Spring (specifically onFailure Method)  which has method with Throwable as argument.                            public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {}  and retrieving part is inside the Servlet Fileter which has HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse as parameters for doFilter method. Probably I am missing something very rudimentary in the Spring space. Thanks.